# Enumerate using tiered numbers

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, labels, enumitem

I want the labels and references of `enumerate` to be tiered numbers, just like the sections/subsections/... is. I have made this code for 4 levels using package `enumitem`, but I'd rather have a simpler code that takes care of all levels at once.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{labelsep=*, leftmargin=*}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{
    label = \arabic*.,
    ref   = \arabic*
}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{
    label = \arabic*.,
    ref   = \theenumi.\arabic*
}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{
    label = \arabic*.,
    ref   = \theenumii.\arabic*
}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{
    label = \arabic*.,
    ref   = \theenumiii.\arabic*
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Enumerate                         \label{itm:1}
    \item Enumerate                         \label{itm:2}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Enumerate                 \label{itm:2.1}
            \item Enumerate                 \label{itm:2.2}
            \item                           \label{itm:2.3}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item Enumerate         \label{itm:2.3.1}
                    \item Enumerate         \label{itm:2.3.2}
                \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
    \item                                   \label{itm:3}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Enumerate                 \label{itm:3.1}
            \item Enumerate                 \label{itm:3.2}
            \item Enumerate                 \label{itm:3.3}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item Enumerate         \label{itm:3.3.1}
                    \item Enumerate         \label{itm:3.3.2}
                    \item Enumerate         \label{itm:3.3.3}
                    \begin{enumerate}
                        \item Enumerate     \label{itm:other}
                        \item Enumerate     \label{itm:other2}
                    \end{enumerate}
                \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\ref{itm:1} \ref{itm:2} \ref{itm:3}

\ref{itm:2.1} \ref{itm:2.2} \ref{itm:2.3}

\ref{itm:2.3.1} \ref{itm:2.3.2}

\ref{itm:3.1} \ref{itm:3.2} \ref{itm:3.3}

\ref{itm:3.3.1} \ref{itm:3.3.2}

\ref{itm:other} \ref{itm:other2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you could use the lower level definitions instead of enumitem, but that is essentially the same. You say it should be like sections, and this is the same. You need to separately specify that subsection uses the prefix section., and susbsubsection uses the prefix section.subsection, you can not specify them all at once.

Comment: How can I do it with lower level definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the labels, you have the `label*` key, which prepends the parent label to the current label. If you want to remove the last dot, you have to specify the ref format per level:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{label*=\arabic*.,labelsep=*, leftmargin=*}
 \setlist[enumerate,1]{ref=\arabic*}
 \setlist[enumerate,2]{ref=\theenumi.\arabic*}
 \setlist[enumerate,3]{ref=\theenumii.\arabic*}
 \setlist[enumerate,4]{ref=\theenumiii.\arabic*}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Enumerate \label{itm:1}
    \item Enumerate \label{itm:2}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Enumerate \label{itm:2.1}
            \item Enumerate \label{itm:2.2}
            \item \label{itm:2.3}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item Enumerate \label{itm:2.3.1}
                    \item Enumerate \label{itm:2.3.2}
                \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
    \item \label{itm:3}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Enumerate \label{itm:3.1}
            \item Enumerate \label{itm:3.2}
            \item Enumerate \label{itm:3.3}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item Enumerate \label{itm:3.3.1}
                    \item Enumerate \label{itm:3.3.2}
                    \item Enumerate \label{itm:3.3.3}
                    \begin{enumerate}
                        \item Enumerate \label{itm:other}
                        \item Enumerate \label{itm:other2}
                    \end{enumerate}
                \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\ref{itm:1} \ref{itm:2} \ref{itm:3}

\ref{itm:2.1} \ref{itm:2.2} \ref{itm:2.3}

\ref{itm:2.3.1} \ref{itm:2.3.2}

\ref{itm:3.1} \ref{itm:3.2} \ref{itm:3.3}

\ref{itm:3.3.1} \ref{itm:3.3.2}

\ref{itm:other} \ref{itm:other2}

\end{document}
```

[image]`

Comment: Thanks. This is better.

Comment: Isn't there an analogous key `ref*`?

Comment: I looked at the package documentation and didn't find one. The problem comes only from the final dot.

Comment: Do you mean the final dot in the ref?

Comment: Yes. The specifications per level are here only to remove the final dot in the references while keeping it for the parent level.

Comment: Ok, I prefer it like this, indeed.

Comment: I fully agree with you. I'd prefer a shorter way, but didn't find one.